# How to put the server's current timestamp into strtotime() function automatically PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a program which counts down over the space of 15 seconds and displays them using PHP and JQuery. I need to be able to automatically load the server's timestamp into the strtotime function and set this to the start point of the timer, and make the end point of the timer 15 seconds after this point, is there any way I can achieve this?

I have tried setting the times specifically and the timer works for counting to 15 seconds after these points, but I need it to set these times relative to the current moment automatically, as I want it to start and stop the timer at certain undecided points in the program as it is running. I have also tried the reference values 'now' and '-15 seconds' - but these seem to stop the timer at '15 seconds remaining' and it does not count down from this point.

timer.php:

```
<?php
if(true) {
    $countdownEnd = strtotime("-15 seconds");
    $countdownStart = strtotime("now");
    $timeLeft = $countdownEnd - $countdownStart;

    if(isset($_POST["type"]) === true && $_POST["type"] == "timerupdate") {
        echo ($timeLeft);
    }
}
?>
```

timer.js:

```
$(function() {
    var timerText = $("[timer]");

    setInterval(function() {
        $.post("timer.php", {type : "timerupdate"}, function(data){
            timerText.html(data + " seconds remaining")
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

timer tests.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="timer.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php include("timer.php") ?>
    <p timer></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be a timer which counts down from 15 seconds whenever the starting condition (the if statement at the beginning of timer.php) becomes true.

Any help is really appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the timer after reload you need something like a session with a cookie. have a look at https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
//start a session and make sure there is no output before 
session_start();
//maybe you want to check for the requestmethod before you do additional checks
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  //your check for timerupdate.
  //you dont have to exact bool compare to true the isset it can only return true or false.
  if (isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"] == "timerupdate") {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) $timeLeft = 15;
    else $timeLeft = 15 - (time() - $_SESSION['time']);
    //output the timer or whatever you want
    if ($timeLeft < 0) echo 0;
    else echo $timeLeft;
  }
}
```

you have to add settings: `withCredentials: true` into your ajax call in order to send cookies

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've made these changes but I still seem to be having the same problem with the timer not counting down, are there any other changes I need to make in order for it to function as intended? Cheers :)

Comment: you have to add settings: `withCredentials: true` into your ajax call in order to send cookies

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with using date function with time .